# Unable to export test case in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using latest version(60.0.2) of firefox and selenium ide(version 3.1.1.0) in Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I am not getting the export test case option in selenium ide.

Could you please suggest me how can I export recorded test case into python webdriver code ?

Answer (score 0):

this version of Selenium IDE doesn't include the export case option. Read the thread about this question that Mohammad kanan put.